# Apache Ignite Key-Value Map high CPU usage

Tags: performance, caching, cpu-usage, ignite, spring-cache

We have configured a Key-Value pair cache using Ignite and Spring Cache integration however we are facing a high CPU usage issue when we try to access the cache object

Cache is initialized with the following parameters:

```
    @Bean   
    public SpringCacheManager getCacheManager(@Autowired Ignite
    ignite) {
        SpringCacheManager cacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
        cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<Object, Object>("defaultDynamicCacheConfig")
               .setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheManager.setDynamicCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);
        return cacheManager;    
    }
```

We have tried various settings such as 
setOnheapCacheEnabled(true)
setSqlOnheapCacheEnabled(true)

but these settings did not help. We also tried nearCache but since we are running Ignite in Server mode it failed.

We are seeing the following in the stack trace when profiling:

```
org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
...
org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:798)
org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:67)
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1773)
```

Comment: Full stack trace has been added below
https://pastebin.com/u6ijhGuJ

Comment: Can you please describe the objects stored in cache? I also recommend trying `setOnheapCacheEnabled(true)` together with `setCopyOnRead(false)` - just make sure to not change objects that you get from cache.

Comment: The object stored in the cache is a complex object containing several fields and fields within those fields. I see where your getting at, while going thru ignite code, I also came across a method which deserializes when a copy is required. I will try this out and let you know. Thank you

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce this locally. I see the issue only when the code participates in a grid of 3 VMs. Am I imagining this or does Ignite behave differently when there is only one VM

Comment: Sure, you have way more marshalling when more than one node is involved. I imagine that your objects may be too complex.

Comment: Your suggestion has fixed the problem. Thank you. The cache mode is replicated, the way I interpreted this is that irrespective of one node or multiple nodes the performance should remain the same because all the objects are available locally. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say, writes will still need to be propagated, for example.